# DDD: Concepts created outside AR, but then attached later on (Crud...?)

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am currently attempting to build a system with DDD to figure out how it works in practice and I might be having trouble wrapping my head around a few problems, mostly related to how bounded contexts work, maybe I have a bad understanding of DDD.

The system is a demo of a bigger system later on, but it basically contains a single feature, shipment planning (the real version would have a ton of logistics related features). The shipment is the Aggregate root. The shipment itself only contains details like shipment number and realized delivery datetime, but it also has the entities:

1. transport order, which contains consignor/consignee info and some
   order specific weight related properties.
2. transport (trailer or
   other vehicle for shipment), transport dimensions and registration
   numbers

Now I would like to be able to create these entities (transport orders and transports) in a different view nothing related to the actual shipment planning yet. This view allows you to create, update or delete any and all transport orders and transports, crud style, so the shipment behaviour is not in these views. Once you press "attach transport" or "attach transport order(s)" in the shipment planning view, the transports or transport orders are actually loaded to the shipment, so they only enter this context once they are loaded:
`Shipment.AttachTransport(Transport transport)` Like so, same for transport order.

Does having CRUD for both transport and transport order make sense? Can I use the same classes I use inside the AR to create and update transports and transport orders in CRUD? Am I missing the point of DDD? Both transports and transport orders can exist in the system without having a parent shipment as well.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand then you'd have 3 aggregate roots: `TransportOrder`, `Transport` & `Shipment`.

> "Does having CRUD for both transport and transport order make sense?"

If there's no more interesting behavior than CRUD for those then sure.

> "Can I use the same classes I use inside the AR to create and update transports and transport orders in CRUD"

No it wouldn't make sense for `TransportOrder` nor `Transport` to live within `Shipment` as they can exist without it, but also because it would make `Shipment` structurally lie about it's transactional boundary as the `Shipment` doesn't own this data -- it's not part of it's transactional boundary. You could however model the relationship by ID for instance.

What you have to ask yourself are questions like:

- What rules/invariants must be enforced when attaching a `Transport` to a `Shipment`. Can you attach a `Transport` to multiple shipments? Is there a limit?
- What rules/invariants must be enforced when attaching `TransportOrder`s to a `Shipment`? E.g. can a `TransportOrder` be attached only to one `Shipment`?
- What should happen if a `TransportOrder` is modified (even deleted) while already attached to a `Shipment`? Should this be allowed?
- Etc.

The answers to those questions will ultimately drive your model because the model shall be optimized for processing commands & protecting invariants. If you have rules crossing multiple AR boundaries then things become more challenging. You either have to consider larger boundaries, modifying more than a single AR per transaction or even accept your model to be eventually consistent.

#### An example

As a concrete exemple, lets say the only rule you have is "A `TransportOrder` can't be attached to more than one `Shipment`".

If you model `Shipment` with a collection of `TransportOrder` like the following then the model wouldn't allow you to enforce that `TransportOrder` wasn't already attached to another `Shipment`. Furthermore, the one-to-many relationship modeled from `Shipment` is useless as there's no invariants to enforce in `Shipment`.

[image]

A more useful model could be to invert the relationship and model the attaching behavior on the `TransportOrder` instead. That way the `TransportOrder` can enforce the only rule where it cannot be attached to more than 1 `Shipment`.

[image]

Now obviously things can get way more tricky and you might ask, well "what happens if the `Shipment` is cancelled"?

There's multiple answers here:

- Perhaps that `TransportOrder` attached to a cancelled `Shipment` will be flagged in an exception report and will have to be re-attached manually?
- Perhaps there's an automated compensating action that will trigger upon the `ShipmentCancelled` event and will unattach the orders.
- Perhaps eventual consistency is not an option and strong consistency is required, in that case you may decide to modify multiple ARs in the same transaction through a domain service. E.g. the `cancelShipment` operation would cancel the shipment and also unattach `TransportOrder`s in a single transaction.

As you can see modeling possibilities are pretty much endless which makes DDD questions very hard to answer without domain-specific knowledge, but hopefully my answer helped you to get on the right track.